# Google Script - Adding Success or Error Message After Execution

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

First time poster and newbie to writing Google Scripts. I have written an importrange script which is working successfully, but I would now like to include some form of error handling to display an alert depending on whether the importrange has run successfully or not. So, if it the function runs successfully to display a success message and if it fails to display an error message. All my attempts so far haven't worked and I'm struggling to identify how I incorporate the correct message depending on the outcome of the function running. Below is a copy of code. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

```
function runsies() {
 
  importRange(
    //Nordics
    "1Xrhx03ub1uXdeFsS0mFZa2zi5uZL-qcuQDbe9oIULQU",
    "DATADUMP: LE!A2:I",
    "1GY-FjVa1XFNpKiR7wx3tCtGUMC2FRbLTORj-wI3iBK8",
    "Nordics - LE!A1"
  );
 
importRange(
    //UK
    "13Y0NOJie1gYWXanQhtkSnTNsx4vt_bcqfUIXj0ePnac",
    "DATADUMP: LE!A2:I",
    "1GY-FjVa1XFNpKiR7wx3tCtGUMC2FRbLTORj-wI3iBK8",
    "UK - LE!A1"
  );

};
 

function importRange(sourceID, sourceRange, destinationID, destinationRangeStart){
 
  // Gather Source range values
  const sourceSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceID);
  const sourceRng = sourceSS.getRange(sourceRange);
  const sourceVals = sourceRng.getValues();
 
  // Get Destiation sheet and cell location.
  const destinationSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(destinationID);
  const destStartRange = destinationSS.getRange(destinationRangeStart);
  const destSheet = destStartRange.getSheet();
 
  // Clear previous data.
  destSheet.clear();
 
  // Get the full data range to paste from start range.
  const destRange = destSheet.getRange(
      destStartRange.getRow(),//Start Row
      destStartRange.getColumn(),//Start Column
      sourceVals.length,//Row Depth
      sourceVals[0].length //Column Width
    );
  
  // Paste in the values
  destRange.setValues(sourceVals);
 
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
};
```

Comment: What exactly have you tried?

Comment: In response to the answer you posted, why hasn't `try()/catch()` worked for you? What have you tried?

Comment: [Edit] to show how you tried `try... catch` and what didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

**Description**

You can use a try {...} catch(err) {...} block to catch any error that may occur in your code or during exection.  And you can use SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert() to display a simple alert dialog box.

**Code.gs**

```
function importRange(sourceID, sourceRange, destinationID, destinationRangeStart){
  try {
    // Gather Source range values
    const sourceSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sourceID);
    //
    // The rest of your code here
    //
    SpreadsheetApp.flush();
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Success");
  }
  catch(err) {
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Error: "+err);
  }
};
```

**Reference**

- [Error handling](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_errors.asp)
- [SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/ui.html#alert(String))